# JUnit5/Maven/Surefire: skipping (or forcing) selected slow unit tests

Tags: maven, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a **Maven** project using **JUnit 5** and **maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2**.

When I execute `mvn clean install` or `mvn test`, I would like a few specific tests
to be skipped - they are either particularly slow, or require other services to be up (= integration tests).

So, I proceed like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;

public class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomethingRegular() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    @Tag("IntegrationTest")
    public void testDatabaseAccess() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And in `pom.xml`, I add this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludedGroups>IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

...

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In general, this works fine. I like the fact that this change is not intrusive - it does not force me to tag each "fast" unit test with e.g. `@Tag("fast")`, and I don't need to add/activate any new Maven profiles.

However, I have 2 questions:

1. After tests are executed, I see `Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`.
   Is it possible for `testDatabaseAccess` to be counted as `Skipped`, instead of being ignored?
2. How to force executing `testDatabaseAccess` on-demand?
   I've tried `mvn test -DincludedGroups=IntegrationTest -DexcludedGroups=aaa`,
   but it did not work...

Comment: move integration tests elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering **question 2** - this can be achieved using Maven profiles:

```
<properties>
    <project.tests.exclude>IntegrationTest</project.tests.exclude>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludedGroups>${project.tests.exclude}</excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

...

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>allTests</id>
        <properties>
            <project.tests.exclude></project.tests.exclude>
        </properties>  
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

By default, executing `mvn clean install` will skip unit tests tagged `IntegrationTest`, while executing `mvn clean install -PallTests` will force all tests to run. And there's no need to declare the `allTests` profile in the `.m2` directory or anywhere else.